# Using md-navbar in Angular4/Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

angular.io, I was not able to find any demo for using md-navbar in the angular 4 (angular) is there any demo available? I tried searching but was not able to find any.

Comment: There is no md-navbar in Angular-Material2? Am I wrong?

Comment: Are you sure? if you check the https://material.angular.io/

they have it on the top

Comment: If you inspect the page, you see its a standard `<nav>` element. You can use their [toolbar](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview) like a navbar if you want, but there is no md-navbar in material2

Comment: I checked in the source code for material 2 the components are there but  no documentation yet.

Comment: It's basically buttons and a nav element. As simple as that. :o

Comment: I dont why the negative points, its not that simple for a developer coming from a non web background. And basically the question was, is md-navbar available or not.

Comment: @SumitVairagar It's not available and sorry for the negativity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use buttons and a toolbar for a navbar (click the image to show the whole screenshot in a new window/tab):

[image: DevTools inspect of material.angular.io]

```html
<md-toolbar color="primary">
    <!-- TBH, I don't think the nav tag is required here -->
    <nav>
        <a md-button routerLink="first">Link #1</a>
        <a md-button routerLink="second">Link #2</a>
        <a md-button routerLink="third">Link #3</a>
        <!-- Etc. -->
    </nav>
</md-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

- [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/navbar-stackoverflow)
- [Live demo](https://navbar-stackoverflow.stackblitz.io)